# Nested range based for loop over vector of pointers

Tags: c++

I have an `albumCollection`, which is of type `vector<Album*>`. My `Album` class, in turn, holds a `vector<Track*>`. This works fine:

```
for(Album* i : albumCollection) {
    cout << i;
}
```

But trying this:

```
for(Album* i : albumCollection) {
    for (Track* j : i) {
        cout << j;
    }
}
```

I get the errors:

`no callable 'begin' function found for type 'Album *'`

and:

`no callable 'end' function found for type 'Album *'`

Comment: `i` is an `Album *`. You want to iterate over `i->tracklist` or whatever it's called.

Comment: `i` is a pointer. You probably want `for (Track* j : *i) {` or similar.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Of course. I feel stupid.

Comment: OT: I would not name either `i` or `j` but instead use a more descriptive name. You will be glad that you did 6 months later when debugging the code so will anyone else having to read the code.

Comment: @drescherjm agreed. Schoolboy error.

Comment: You could add `begin` and `end` functions to `Album` that return iterators from `tracklist`. That way the user has no need to know that the `vector` exists at all.

Comment: On a side note, I am 99.9% sure you do not need your vector to contain pointers to Album or Track.

Comment: Extending from @SergeyA 's point, if you elect to go the pointer route, make sure you are familiar with and correctly observing [The Rule of Three and friends](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Answer (score 3):

You need the vector that is contained in each `Album` to be on the right hand side of the `:` in the nested loop.  That would look like

```
for(Album* album : albumCollection) {
    for (Track* track : album->name_of_vector) {
        cout << track;
    }
}
```

Comment: Absolutely. Can't believe I didn't twig. Thankyou

Comment: I am also certain that neither albumCollection, nor track vector need to be a vector of raw pointers.